# С чего начать изучать искусственный интеллект

Tags: искусственный-интеллект

Хочу начать изучать искусственный интеллект, машинное обучение и все связанное с этим. Но к сожалению ничего толком нормального и адекватного для новичков в этом деле найти не могу. Только GeekBrains, но им не доверяю и 12500 р/месяц как-то платить за это не хочется. 
Кто связан с этой сферой не могли бы подсказать с чего начать, какие есть учебные материалы для того, чтобы получить правильные фундаментальные знания (желательно на русском).
И еще заметил тенденцию, что все что связано с машинным обучением заточено под python... На сколько сильно он оказывает влияние на эту сферу? Я являюсь junior в С++ и он гораздо удобнее, понятнее для меня + ко всему он гораздо быстрее python, смогу ли я с такой же спокойной душой работать с ИИ используя плюсы или все таки лучше овладеть python? Вообще не откажусь от советов по изучению ИИ

Comment: Python, нейронные сети, google, coursera, udemy в конце концов, но не GeekBrains. Раз уж вам хватило понимания по поводу GB, уверен вы освоите тему ИИ